# Can I safely kill OPTIMIZE TABLE on an InnoDB table?

Tags: mysql, innodb, mysql-5.5, database-tuning

MySQL's documentation for `kill` [warns](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/kill.html):

> **Warning**
>
> Killing a `REPAIR TABLE` or `OPTIMIZE TABLE` operation on a `MyISAM` table results in a table that is corrupted and unusable. Any reads or writes to such a table fail until you optimize or repair it again (without interruption).

That's for MyISAM.

Is it also unsafe to kill an `OPTIMIZE TABLE` process running against an InnoDB table?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

According to MySQL Certification Guide :

> The OPTIMIZE TABLE statement cleans up a MyISAM table by defragmenting
>   it. This involves reclaiming unused space resulting from deletes and
>   updates, and coalescing records that have become split and stored
>   non-contiguously. OPTIMIZE TABLE also sorts the index pages if they
>   are out of order and updates the index statistics
>
> Also works for InnoDB tables, but maps to ALTER TABLE, which rebuilds
>   the table. This updates index statistics and frees space in the
>   clustered index.

So In Case of InnoDB :

Innodb is ACID compliant, the optimize table simply copies all records into a new table

1. If the index pages are not sorted, sort them,
2. If the table's statistics are not up to date (and the repair could not be accomplished by sorting the index), update them.
3. If the table has deleted or split rows, repair the table.

And if you try to kill it when it's running you will not loose any records.

Additionally, case of InnoDB with `innodb_defragment=1`, there will be no ROLLBACK required, as in this case `OPTIMIZE TABLE` is incremental.

Comment: The kill is no problem. As Abdul mentioned it make a copy. You can check this when you make a `show processlist` and you'll see a `copy to tmp table`